# Correlation of the result of an algorithm to the coefficient of variation of the input

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, algorithms

Let $A$ and $B$ be two algorithms to solve the same problem and $f(.)$ be the evaluation criteria of the solutions. I use $\frac{f(A(I))}{f(B(I))}$ to find the relative performance of the two algorithms. Both $A$ and $B$ take a list of positive numbers as input. I want to show that algorithm $A$ works much better (compared to $B$) if the input $I$ has a higher coefficient of variation. Assume $X$ is the vector of coefficient of variation of the inputs and $Y$ is the relative performance of the algorithms as described above. Here is a plot of "coefficient of variation" vs "performance ratio" for 2000 randomly generated inputs:

[image]

Correlation of the "coefficient of variation" and "performance ratio" for the sample data is about $0.87$. Now, I have two questions:

1. Based on the above data, can I say the variables are strongly correlated?
2. What sort of other analysis/plot can I use to show the correlation if them clearly?

Edit: I asked quite a similar question at [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/showing-the-correlation-of-two-variables-using-a-plot) and got an answer. I'll put the answer below.

Comment: Please when you cross-post mention it, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2411. There is still a good chance you will get good answers at the Mathematica site.

Comment: From that plot, seems to me that method A *always* performs substantially better than method B. Its advantage grows somewhat with the CV, but A has around 40% better performance even for low CV.

Comment: @AndyW: Thanks Andy. Is there any formal way to connect the cross-post questions or should I simply link to the question?

Comment: @onestop: That's right. $A$ always perform better but is the analysis/plot the best one I can do to show the correlation?

Comment: A link is sufficient, although it is generally discouraged to cross post (especially within such a short time frame). If you get a reasonable answer at the Mathematica site just make sure to post the reply here for reference (and vice-versa). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

### **Note:** Thanks to Chris Degnen, I've got a nice answer for the question at [Mathematica.ES](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/showing-the-correlation-of-two-variables-using-a-plot) website. Below is the copied answer.

You can also calculate the [Coefficient of Determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination), R Squared.

This is the same as the [correlation squared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient), but by making use of `LinearModelFit` you can create some additional graphics.

To make a sample distribution you can use this:

```
CreateDistribution[] := DynamicModule[{savepts = {{-1, -1}}},
  Dynamic[
   EventHandler[
    ListPlot[pts, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 5}}], 
    "MouseDown" :> (savepts = 
       pts = DeleteCases[
         Append[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"]], {-1, -1}])],
   Initialization :> (pts = savepts)]]

CreateDistribution[]
```

Just click to add some points.  The data is collected in the variable `pts`.

[image]

Then calculate R Squared:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[Sort@pts, a, a]; r2 = lm["RSquared"];
Show[Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 7}], ListPlot[pts], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "The correlation is " <> 
   If[D[lm["BestFit"], a] < 0, "negative", "positive"], 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Style[
    "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"R\", \"2\"]\) = " <> ToString[r2], 
    11], {1.5, 4.5}]]
```

[image]

Whether the correlation is positive or negative is obtained here from the derivative of the `BestFit`.

You can add standard deviation bands for [sigma = 1, 2 & 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) like this.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[Sort@pts, {1, x (*, x^2 *)}, x];
{bands68[x_], bands95[x_], bands99[x_]} = 
  Table[lm["SinglePredictionBands", 
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {0.6827, 0.9545, 0.9973}}];
Show[ListPlot[Sort@pts], 
 Plot[{lm[x], bands68[x], bands95[x], bands99[x]}, {x, -0.15, 7.2}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 5}}, ImageSize -> 480, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Uncomment `x^2` for a quadratic fit.

[image]